# 7zip archive won't decrypt with the password used for encryption

Tags: command-line, powershell, encryption, passwords, 7-zip

I'm trying to write a PowerShell script that will use 7zip to compress files with encryption individually.

```
$Password = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter Password:'

dir *.txt | ForEach-Object -Parallel { & 7z a -t7z -mm=LZMA2 -mx=9 -md=1024m -mfb=273 -ms=64g -myx=9 -mmt=32 -p$Password ($_.BaseName+".7z") $_.Name }
```

This works during the compression phase but the compressed files cannot be decrypted and extracted with the password used for encryption.
The output of GUI during decompression is below.

```
Data error : Wrong password? test.txt
```

This error is not present if I use the GUI during the compression process. Any help is appretiated.

Comment: Does your password have spaces or special characters in it? You may need to wrap your `-p$Password` in quotes.

Comment: Special (non-ASCII) characters can be mapped to different binary values in GUI and command-line applications. If the password works in GUI and not in command-line you are facing an encoding problem. Better use a longer password that only makes use of ASCII characters.

Comment: It does but something as simple as `abc` or `123` don't work as well. Escaping with double quotes freezes the script and using single quotes takes `$Password` literally. The charset is the extended IBM ASCII charset so no non-ASCII characters are present in the password.

Answer (score 2):

Powershell treats `-p$Password` as an argument name, and doesn't expand the `$`. Either add a space between `-p` and `$Password`, or use `Start-Process` with a quoted argument list instead of `Call`/`&`:

```
Start-Process 'C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe' -ArgumentList `
    "a -t7z -mm=LZMA2 -mx=9 -md=1024m -mfb=273 -ms=64g -myx=9 -mmt=32 -p$Password $($_.BaseName+".7z") $($_.Name)"
```

I tested with my 7zip and it was able to use the password correctly.

Comment: I tried using this on a bunch of files named like `New Text Document`, `New Text Document Copy`, `New Text Document Copy (2)` and so on using a password like ``

Comment: (2/2) `\άÌ-;Δ7RÕκOhδ┌ñ©FÉ®Ô¶ϿϽΫ.ΕΗβ¯à║þQÀϖύLεπί5ΤøÙϕν²┴@ΘèÚG¿´Ωpγ■v¸^{ξΊ$!NµTσ═ϋ¤y≡ϲm▄ íWZ%ϑªÖΝ┤ͻ«8ËÄ×æãϒτμΨa6ó▓ÿ¥K¡ÜαYÒ┐,Κ&¦Ϲ§|υJÍΡρήo`, but I could not get an output. Got a single `.7z` file that was unextractable. I placed the code into between the braces of the ForEach-Object.